# CSS grid calendar with moment.js

Tags: javascript

I liked the css grid calendar with the moment js library. But I want the grid to consist of 35 blocks of the required color and there are no empty white blocks.

I tried to create 35 blocks using innerHTML at first, but I didn't figure out how to insert dates into these blocks.

Help me please.

```
let calendarDay = document.createElement('div')
    if (day === 1) {
        calendarDay.setAttribute('style', `grid-column-start:${firstDay}`)
        console.log(`firstDay = ${firstDay}`)
    }
```

[My Codepen](https://codepen.io/sk1p96/pen/XWpLgQd)

[Codepen original](https://codepen.io/webdevwill/pen/Xvxaxd)

Answer (score 1):

We can just add empty cells before first day and after last day in the calendar with a few lines of the code.

```js
let calendarSettings = {
  date: moment().set('date', 1),
  today: moment()
}

const incrementMonth = () => {
  calendarSettings.date.add(1, 'Months')
  console.log(`incremented to ${calendarSettings.date}`)
  displayCalendar(calendarSettings)
}

const decrementMonth = () => {
  calendarSettings.date.subtract(1, 'Months')
  console.log(`decremented to ${calendarSettings.date}`)
  displayCalendar(calendarSettings)
}

const displayCalendar = (calendarSettings) => {

  const calendar = document.querySelector('.calendar-grid')
  
  const calendarTitle = calendarSettings.date.format('MMMM YYYY')
  const daysInMonth = calendarSettings.date.endOf('Month').date()
  const firstDay = calendarSettings.date.startOf('Month').isoWeekday()

  calendar.innerHTML = ''
  calendar.innerHTML = `
                        <div class="calendar-nav"><a onClick="decrementMonth()">&lt; </a></div>
                        <div class="calendar-title">${calendarTitle}</div>
                        <div class="calendar-nav calendar-nav__right"><a onClick="incrementMonth()"> &gt;</a></div>
                        <div class="calendar-dayname">Monday</div>
                        <div class="calendar-dayname">Tuesday</div>
                        <div class="calendar-dayname">Wednesday</div>
                        <div class="calendar-dayname">Thursday</div>
                        <div class="calendar-dayname">Friday</div>
                        <div class="calendar-dayname">Saturday</div>
                        <div class="calendar-dayname">Sunday</div>
                        `
  
  for (let day = 1; day <= daysInMonth; day++) {
    let calendarDay = document.createElement('div')
    if (day === 1) {
      calendarDay.setAttribute('style', `grid-column-start:${firstDay}`)
      console.log(`firstDay = ${firstDay}`)
    }
    calendarDay.classList.add('calendar-day')
    if (calendarSettings.today.month() == calendarSettings.date.month() && calendarSettings.today.year() == calendarSettings.date.year()) {
      if (calendarSettings.today.date() == day) {
        calendarDay.classList.add('current-day')
      }
    }
    calendarDay.innerHTML = day
    calendar.appendChild(calendarDay)
  }

  for (let index = 1; index < firstDay; index++) {
    let calendarDay = document.createElement('div')
    calendarDay.classList.add('calendar-day')
    calendar.insertBefore(calendarDay, calendar.querySelector('.calendar-day'))
  }

  let lastDay = (firstDay + daysInMonth) % 7
  if (lastDay === 0) {
    lastDay = 7;
  }
  
  if (lastDay > 1) {
    for (let index = lastDay; index <= 7 ; index++) {
      let calendarDay = document.createElement('div')
      calendarDay.classList.add('calendar-day')
      calendar.appendChild(calendarDay)
    }
  }
}

displayCalendar(calendarSettings);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  
  margin:0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  color: #666;
  background:lightgoldenrodyellow;

}

.calendar-grid {
  margin:1em auto;
  width:80%;
  height: 80vh;
  grid-gap: 10px 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 3em 2em;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  border-top: 4px solid palegoldenrod;
  padding-top:1em;
}

.calendar-day {
  padding:.4em;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background:palegoldenrod;
  border-radius:5px;
}

.current-day {
  background:lightskyblue;
}

.first-day {
  grid-column-start: 4;
}

.calendar-dayname {
  padding:.4em;
  text-align:center;
  background:goldenrod;
  color:palegoldenrod;
}

.calendar-title {
  text-align:center;
  grid-column: 2 / -2;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.calendar-nav a {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  font-size: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.calendar-nav__right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title></title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

  
  <div class="calendar-grid">
  
  </div>
  
<script src="moment.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks good, but there's a snafu in July.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! But  @ZacharyHaber is right(

Comment: It should be fixed. My bad math. :)

Answer (score 1):

Same general idea as Richard's answer: Add cells before and after the main calendar days. Which lets you also remove the extra logic for the first day's `grid-column-start`

Just with a difference in logic on the adding extra cells.

```
  const daysOver7 = (firstDay + daysInMonth - 1) % 7;
  if (daysOver7) {
    for (let day = 0; day < 7 - daysOver7; day++) {
      let calendarDay = document.createElement("div");
      calendarDay.classList.add("calendar-day");
      calendar.appendChild(calendarDay);
    }
  }
```

```js
let calendarSettings = {
  date: moment().set("date", 1),
  today: moment(),
};

const incrementMonth = () => {
  calendarSettings.date.add(1, "Months");
  console.log(`incremented to ${calendarSettings.date}`);
  displayCalendar(calendarSettings);
};

const decrementMonth = () => {
  calendarSettings.date.subtract(1, "Months");
  console.log(`decremented to ${calendarSettings.date}`);
  displayCalendar(calendarSettings);
};

const displayCalendar = (calendarSettings) => {
  const calendar = document.querySelector(".calendar-grid");

  const calendarTitle = calendarSettings.date.format("MMMM YYYY");
  const daysInMonth = calendarSettings.date.endOf("Month").date();
  const firstDay = calendarSettings.date.startOf("Month").isoWeekday();

  calendar.innerHTML = "";
  calendar.innerHTML = `
                        <div class="calendar-nav"><a onClick="decrementMonth()">&lt; </a></div>
                        <div class="calendar-title">${calendarTitle}</div>
                        <div class="calendar-nav calendar-nav__right"><a onClick="incrementMonth()"> &gt;</a></div>
                        <div class="calendar-dayname">Monday</div>
                        <div class="calendar-dayname">Tuesday</div>
                        <div class="calendar-dayname">Wednesday</div>
                        <div class="calendar-dayname">Thursday</div>
                        <div class="calendar-dayname">Friday</div>
                        <div class="calendar-dayname">Saturday</div>
                        <div class="calendar-dayname">Sunday</div>
                        `;
  for (let day = 1; day < firstDay; day++) {
    let calendarDay = document.createElement("div");
    calendarDay.classList.add("calendar-day");
    calendar.appendChild(calendarDay);
  }
  for (let day = 1; day <= daysInMonth; day++) {
    let calendarDay = document.createElement("div");
    calendarDay.classList.add("calendar-day");
    if (
      calendarSettings.today.month() == calendarSettings.date.month() &&
      calendarSettings.today.year() == calendarSettings.date.year()
    ) {
      if (calendarSettings.today.date() == day) {
        calendarDay.classList.add("current-day");
      }
    }
    calendarDay.innerHTML = day;
    calendar.appendChild(calendarDay);
  }
  const daysOver7 = (firstDay + daysInMonth - 1) % 7;
  if (daysOver7) {
    for (let day = 0; day < 7 - daysOver7; day++) {
      let calendarDay = document.createElement("div");
      calendarDay.classList.add("calendar-day");
      calendar.appendChild(calendarDay);
    }
  }
};

displayCalendar(calendarSettings);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  color: #666;
  background: lightgoldenrodyellow;
}

.calendar-grid {
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80vh;
  grid-gap: 10px 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 3em 2em;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  border-top: 4px solid palegoldenrod;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

.calendar-day {
  padding: .4em;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: palegoldenrod;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.current-day {
  background: lightskyblue;
}

.first-day {
  grid-column-start: 4;
}

.calendar-dayname {
  padding: .4em;
  text-align: center;
  background: goldenrod;
  color: palegoldenrod;
}

.calendar-title {
  text-align: center;
  grid-column: 2 / -2;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.calendar-nav a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.calendar-nav__right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Calendar Experiment</title>

</head>

<body>


  <div class="calendar-grid">

  </div>

  <script src="moment.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```